# Find probability when distribution is given by a formula

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

Given the probability density function:
$g(x)=Cx^{-3}1_{[1,5]}(x)=
\begin{cases}
Cx^{-3}\ \text{for} \ 1\le x\le 5\\
0 \ \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Find $P(\frac{1}{x} \in [0.5,3])$.
Obviously first I need to find $C$, but that's simple I need to calculate the integral and make it equal to one. However I do not know how to calculate this probability is this the same as: $P(\frac{1}{x} \in [0.5,3])=P(x \in [1/3, 2])$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Now I expect you can finish the calculation.  Note that this is the same as $\Pr(1\le X\le 2)$.

Comment: Thus it will be $\int_{1/3}^2 Cx^{-3} dx$? I will manage to calculate the value of the integral on my own.

Comment: There is a little twist, because the density function of $X$ is $0$ between $1/3$ and $1$.  So the integral in your previous comment is not quite right.

Comment: $\int_{1}^2 Cx^{-3} dx$ now it's ok?

Comment: Yes, now it is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. Formally that is
$$
P(\frac{1}{x} \in [0.5,3]) = P(0.5 \leq \frac1x\leq 3)
=P(x\leq 2, x>\frac{1}{3} ) = P(x\in[\frac13, 2]).
$$
Then, as we have a density function
$$
P(\frac{1}{x} \in [0.5,3]) = \int\limits_{1/3}^2 g(t)\, dt.
$$